# LaunchUriAsync with authentication

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, ms-office, uri

I've got the following code line opening a document from a Sharepoint Document library

```
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

Everthings works fine, but when I open a document (let's just say a word document for exemple), the user has to put his login/password before any interaction with the document.

Is there any way to add the authentication informations to `LaunchUriAsyncMethod` ?

Thanks for your help